# Azure Application Gateway Timeout #long running process

Tags: azure, connection-timeout, azure-application-gateway, long-running-processes, azure-waf

We are using Azure Application Gateway with WAF. We have configured a timeout of 3600 seconds, and we performed the following scenario with Azure WAF and without WAF:

With Azure: The application runs around 1 hour and then shows 504 Error.

And without Azure, the Application got the result within 20 to 30 minutes.

Could you please help with this issue?

Comment: Could you please share the `backend health status` of the gateway once, so that we can reproduce this scenario? If we get a `504 error`, it could be due to an `unhealthy state`. As per my initial analysis, this issue may be caused by the timeout threshold in the probe settings. Please increase the timeout on health probe and please refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-backend-health-troubleshooting)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. we have already increased the timeout value and server state is healthy. Our application smoothly works without Azure Application Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Either in Azure Application Gateway also we can get good results by doing like this

Update Backend Settings either http / https protocols request time-out to example 3600 sec

[image]
Create an health probe to test our application is working fine or not

[image]

Test the health probe, depends on the output we can figure out the issues. if any firewall block, please allow those ports from NSG.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We have already tried requesting time-out to 1200 secs, which was not working.